# Aplicar funcão condicional com três retornos possíveis

Tags: r, if, condição, else

Preciso de ajuda com um exercício de condicional, por favor. O objetivo é identificar se o valor da coluna `data$variacao` é positiva e incluir, na coluna `data$updown` `+1`. Se for negativa, `-1` e `0` se não houve variação.

Pensei em criar com `if` `else`, mas ao usar o `return()`, não estou tendo sucesso. Muito obrigado!

```
data$variacao == 0

if (data$variacao > 0) {
    return(data$UpDown <- +1)
} else if (data$variacao  < 0) {
    return (data$UpDown <- -1)
} else if (data$variacao == 0) {
    return(data$UpDown <- 0)
}
```

Comment: Olá nino machado! Você poderia incluir um exemplo de dados que possa ser reproduzido, por favor? Não é claro para mim o que há na coluna `data$variacao`. Ela é uma coluna de uma tabela que contém diversos valores? O resultado desejado seria uma nova coluna, com o mesmo número de elementos que `data$variacao` contendo `integers`:  `1`, `-1`  e `0` para cada condição? Veja o link sobre formulação de perguntas: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r

Comment: Oi Jose, me desculpe. Tem razão. O exercício pedia para considerar a diferença na quantidade de passageiros ano a no numa companhia, data$passengers. Para criar a interação, então, criei uma nova coluna chamada data$variacao, atraves da função diff(data$passengers). Assim, o objetivo é analisar essa variação e, popular a coluna data$UpDown, se foi +1 (para positivos), -1 (para negativos) e zero (quando não houve variação). Espero ter explicado melhor, vou olhar o link que enviou. Obrigado!

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta é dada em uma instrução do R base, veja `help("sign")`. Não são necessários `if`, `ifelse` ou ciclos `for`.
Com os dados da resposta do [Jose](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/544115/82237), será

```r
data$UpDown <- sign(data$variacao)
data
#>    id variacao UpDown
#> 1   a       30      1
#> 2   b        0      0
#> 3   c      -30     -1
#> 4   d        0      0
#> 5   e       30      1
#> 6   f        0      0
#> 7   g      -30     -1
#> 8   h        0      0
#> 9   i      -30     -1
#> 10  j       30      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Excelente, Rui!! Muito obrigado, amigo!!!

Answer (score 2):

Para iterar é necessário processar cada item que compõe o vector ou coluna.

Por isso é recomendável:

- Criar um vector ou coluna com igual número de elementos que a coluna que será avaliada para alocar os resultados
- Utilizar a função `for` seguida de `seq_along()`
- Indicar cada item que será processado e cada item que será substituído nas colunas ("i")

### Tabela com dados para exemplo

```
set.seed(40)

data <- data.frame(
    id = letters[1:10],
    variacao = sample(c(-30, 0, 30), 10, TRUE))

data
```

### Alocar valores a ser iterados incluindo valores como `integer`

```
data$UpDown <- rep(0, length(data$variacao))

for (i in seq_along(data$variacao)){
    if (data$variacao[i] > 0)
        data$UpDown[i] <- 1L
     else if (data$variacao[i] < 0)
        data$UpDown[i] <- -1L
     else if(data$variacao[i] == 0)
        data$UpDown[i] <- 0L
}
```

### Alocar valores a ser iterados incluindo valores como `character`

```
data$UpDownc <- rep(0, length(data$variacao))

for (i in seq_along(data$variacao)){
    if (data$variacao[i] > 0)
        data$UpDownc[i] <- "+1"
     else if (data$variacao[i] < 0)
        data$UpDownc[i] <- "-1"
     else if(data$variacao[i] == 0)
        data$UpDownc[i] <- "0"
}
```

### Uma versão vetorizada

O mesmo resultado, mas indexando os valores usando a função "extract" `[`.

```
data$UpDownv <- data$variacao

data[data$UpDownv == 0, "UpDownv"] <- 0
data[data$UpDownv > 0, "UpDownv"] <- 1
data[data$UpDownv < 0, "UpDownv"] <- -1
```

### Usando função vetorizada `ifelse()`

A função pode ser aplicada nesse caso, da seguinte maneira:

```
data$UpDownv2 <- ifelse(data$variacao == 0, 0,
                 ifelse(data$variacao > 0, 1, -1))
```

### Resultado

```
> head(data)
  id variacao UpDown UpDownc UpDownv UpDownv2
1  a       30      1      +1       1        1
2  b        0      0       0       0        0
3  c      -30     -1      -1      -1       -1
4  d        0      0       0       0        0
5  e       30      1      +1       1        1
6  f        0      0       0       0        0
```

Comment: Ola Jose, Obrigado! Tentei fazer com a opção de integer e devolveu com este erro: Error in if (data$variacao[i] > 0) data$UpDown[i] <- 1L else if (data$variacao[i] <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.    Preciso declarar algo antes? Aproveitando, pq devo usar o "L" após o número? Grato

Comment: A mensagem pode ser porque existam dados perdidos ou por alguma particularidade nos dados. Se consegues rodar o exemplo, mas não consegues aplicar o código a teus dados, pode ser isso. O "L" é para indicar que os valores são números inteiros (`integer`). De qualquer maneira, se não estás elaborando o código para um exercicio e a ideia é fazer a transformação da variável, a resposta do @Rui Barradas é ótima para resolver o problema.

Comment: esclarecido! obrigado!